# Assistance with Permission Denied error in WebSphere plugin

Tags: websphere

Some details first:

- WebSphere 9 installed on Windows server
- WebSphere 9 plugin installed on CentOS 7 with Apache (currently used as reverse proxy)
- WebSphere 9 plugin installed on Rocky Linux with Apache (to be used as reverse proxy)

I didn't install the Windows or CentOS systems above.  I want to replace CentOS with Rocky.

I installed the WebSphere plugin on Rocky and replicated the plugin config.  When attempting to use the Rocky server to connect to the Windows server I get an internal server error and the following error in the httpd log:

> ERROR: ws_common: websphereGetStream: Failed to connect to app server on host 'windowsserver.domain' (OS err=13): Permission denied (local port 0, address 1/1)

The Rocky server can resolve the windowsserver.domain hostname and there are no firewall issues.

The only thing I can think of is perhaps there is somewhere in the Windows WebSphere server config that restricts what can connect to it (something other than the firewall), but if so I don't know where that is.

Can anyone advise what I might be missing?

thanks

jc

EDIT: I can't find anything in the WebSphere logs on the Windows server.

EDIT EDIT: I have never installed anything WebSphere before.  I can see some plugin-key.kdb/.rdb/.sth files which I had copied across from the existing CentOS system along with the plugin-cfg.xml file.

Comment: A blind guess, but check the plugin file/directory permissions, and plugin-cfg.xml file permissions, as by default they are replicated with root rights if I remember correctly. So the Apache may not be able to read them while running.

Comment: Check this, it talks about IHS but might be relevant for your setup also https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/tihs_setperm.htm

Comment: Thanks guys (didn't notice your comments here, I must have notifications turned off!)  I have replicated the file permissions as they are on the existing reverse proxy server.  Hard to tell what permission is being denied.  I assumed it was the WebSphere server doing the denying.

Answer (score 0):

Dang it!  It ended up being selinux!  Ports 9080-9082 were being used for the WebSphere servers so selinux needed to give permission for it!  Stupid mistake.